# For ECA, how can I create a flag that unpublishes a comment, using 'classic modeller'?

Tags: flags

Rules and Rules_flag is not working well in Drupal 10.1, though I had a solution working in Drupal 9.5.

The goal: a flag on each comment that unpublishes the comment, when a user clicks the flag.

Since this no longer works in Drupal 10, I've attempted to create this solution in ECA module with ECA_flag and the Classic Modeller (eca_cm).

The modeler is mystifying, however.
I'm pretty much randomly keying in guesses and selecting random values from dropdowns.

Can anyone who has been able to build this functionality with ECM share an example?  An example using any of the modelers would be helpful. Since this is a very basic use case, I've gone with Classic Modeller, but I'm not married to it.

Answer (score 1):

Asking for examples is off topic for this site, so the question will probably be closed.

Unfortunately, the Flag module is not currently actively maintained, so it's a bit hard to find examples.

However, I would suggest skipping Rules/ECA and doing this all in a custom module.  This is because if you do it in a custom module, it will continue to work in new Drupal versions unless Flag itself changes, whereas with Rules/ECA, you may get left behind in Drupal version updates.

I would take the following approach:

1. Use `hook_entity_type_update()` for the flagging.
2. Confirm that you have the right type of flagging (check the flag bundle).
3. Get the comment entity id from `$flagging->field_comment_entity_reference->target_id`.
4. Unpublish the comment.

Comment: Thanks. I was starting to think along similar lines... make a module. I was thinking of skipping Flag also, though. How hard is it to create a link on each comment that does a perm check then unpublishes?  But I'm a sitebuilder, not really a developer, so it will take a good bit of digging and trial and error to code that I suspect.  .... any shortcuts appreciated. I have created a few other super simple modules, so I know basically how to set up the file structure, but not much more.

Comment: @aharown07 I can't say how hard it is, but I also went from site builder to module developer, and I basically rewrote the Flag module for my latest project, so I know it can be done.  People on this site can be very helpful if you take the time to do your research and identify exactly where you are stuck.